# Xcode 4, View-based Application + UITableView crashes when scroll up

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, crash, scroll

In Xcode start a new project with the View-based Application template (iPhone only).

In the xib for the view (ProjectNameViewController.xib) with Interface Builder, add a TableView.

Create a new Objective-C class subclass of UITableView, in the header file add the UITableViewDataSource protocol and add this attribute:

```
NSArray *data;
```

In the implementation file implement the 2 required methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString* identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

In the init method add this:

```
data = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil] retain];
```

Back to Interface Builder, add a new object with the previous custom class (Identity inspector).
In the UITableView (in Interface Builder on the Connections inspector) add the outlet dataSource to the previous object.

Run the application, it show the table with the data then when you scroll up it crashed with signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the main-thread (no exception thrown).

I'm barely new to Xcode + Interface Builder with the Cocoa Framework, I'm trying to understand the Movel-View-Controller for create apps that have reusable code but I can't understand how I can divide objects for make controllers for each UI element in the application, because in this case if I put the methods on the class sub-classed by the File's Owner (with the protocol in the same way of the class above) it all works.
But the class of the File's Owner is the ViewController and I want the TableView separate from any other object in the application. If this is not the way for build an application (the recommended way), tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding in Diagnostics "Enable Zombie Objects" I have this output: Target Output: ViewBasedApp[859:b303] *** -[TableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x522be0

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved.

In the ViewController add 2 IBOutlet:

One for the UITableView and one for the TableViewController (example):

```
@interface ViewBasedAppViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *table;
    IBOutlet TableViewController *tableController;
}
```

The TableViewController is a NSObject. 
In Interface Builder connect the outlets:
From the File's owner to the table select "table";
From the File's owner to the TableViewController object select "tableController";